# Optimize pass parameter to view

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I have quite complicated view in mysql, like

```
select filter.id as filter_id, person.id, person.name
from person, filter
inner  join 
...
left join
...
where person_match_filter_condition ...
group by filter.filter_id, person.id, person.name
```

Query filters person which corresponds domain specific conditions.

Typical use of view is:

```
select * from where filter_id = some_value
```

Problem is that mysql cannot optimize query. It applies confition by filter_id AFTER get data for all filters - very ineffective.
Idea to get filter_id from other tables is not good for my case.

How can I transform my query to make it more effective?

Comment: @burnall use a four space indent instead of `<blockquote>` tags for code blocks. I updated your question for you.

Comment: Do you use indexes? I also helps

Comment: Yes, there are several indexes.
Problem is not in them

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the long query in a procedure, and pass the filters to the procedure call as parameters. Then instead of using views you call the procedure, the procedure will build you the entire query and will run  optimized query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I have considered this. Unfortunately:

1) I cannot provide for every possible parameter, I need to join the query flexibly with lots other conditions. I do not want use dynamic SQL.

2) Java back-end uses Hibernate. Stored procedures are compatible 
with ORM badly.

Any further ideas?

Comment: Just provide 1 string as parameter, the full clause you passed to the view. I don't know Hibernate, I can't help you on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, you can pass parameters to your views in a simple manner by creating a Function to GET your values from Session Variables. See https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/14511760 for the technique. This is a copy of my create function you may wish to pattern after.
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION fn_getcase_id()
RETURNS MEDIUMINT(11)
DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN

## see stackoverflow.com/questions/14511760 and read ALL the info TWICE or MORE.  wh 04/13/2017

```
RETURN @sv_case_id;
```

END//

DELIMITER ;
You will need to create a similar FN (one for each variable).