# Need a MySQL workaround to pass a variable \ parameter into view?

Tags: mysql, view, sql-view

I would like to pass a variable\parameter into a view to filter by a date range.  Since I am doing grouping in the view I can not put the where clause externally to the view.

I have read a bunch of posts on this but have not been able to get it working yet. Most workaround I have seen to pass a parameter into a view involve using a function to return the value and this is where I am getting stuck.

```
/* My current view that I want to pass in start and end dates */
CREATE VIEW Total_Sales_By_Product_Num AS
SELECT products_all_fields.*,
    Sum(<a bunch of code removed for this sample>) AS Item_Qty_Requested_Total, 
    Sum(<a bunch of code removed for this sample>) AS Item_Qty_Accepted_Total,  
    Sum(<a bunch of code removed for this sample>) AS Total_Sales_Dollars
FROM products_all_fields
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (web_orders_items
        INNER JOIN web_orders_header
            ON  web_orders_items.Web_Order_Num = web_orders_header.Web_Order_Num )
        ON  products_all_fields.Product_Num = web_orders_items.Product_Num
WHERE web_orders_header.Order_Date BETWEEN fn_GetStartDate() AND fn_GetEndDate()
GROUP BY products_all_fields.Product_Num
ORDER BY products_all_fields.Description
```

The functions to return the parameters to the view:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_GetStartDate ()
    RETURNS DATE
    DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN
    RETURN @StartDate;
END

CREATE FUNCTION fn_GetEndDate ()
    RETURNS DATE
    DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN
    RETURN @EndDate;
END
```

This does not work, it returns no data, I know I am doing something stupid

```
set @fn_StartDate := '2012-01-01';
set @fn_EndDate := '2012-02-01';
select * from Total_Sales_By_Product_Num
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahhh!!! I got it working, I feel like an idiot but I had double quotes not single quotes in one of my assignments of the dates.  It seems to work now.  I will leave this post up for future people searching how to do this.

Comment: Melanie, I had double quotes on one of my assignment operators, the set @fn_StartDate := '2012-01-01; command.  One I fixed that it worked.  So all the code in the first post should work.

Comment: So you *can* pass parameters to a View? When did that become possible? I missed the memo. ;)

Comment: You can not directly pass parameters to a view, you have to do a bit of a hack workaround.  Not the cleanest thing but it works.

Answer (score 1):

It should be work as below:

```
set @StartDate := '2012-01-01';
set @EndDate := '2012-02-01';
select * from Total_Sales_By_Product_Num;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
SET @fn_StartDate = fn_GetStartDate('2012-01-01')
```

same with @fn_EndDate

and then in your view

```
WHERE web_orders_header.Order_Date BETWEEN @fn_StartDate.....
```

However, that's just the syntax of how to call a function. You're still trying to pass a parameter to a view, which is not possible, as far as I know. Try putting all your View logic in the function instead.

Comment: What is the dbo?  Is that the schema name?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm assuming dbo schema. Shouldn't have done that. It's gone now.

Comment: Moving everything into the function seems more reasonable!