# Passing parameter to MySQL View

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to pass a parameter to a view that I have created.
This is my code.

```
CREATE FUNCTION param1() RETURNS VARCHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC NO SQL RETURN @param1;
CREATE VIEW `view_stats` AS SELECT * FROM `history` WHERE fullname = param1() ;
```

This is my query

```
SELECT st.*, mtr.max_open_trades, mtr.max_draw_down FROM `view_stats` AS ST INNER JOIN `mtrecords` AS mtr ON st.login = mtr.login WHERE st.login=?
```

How can I pass a parameter to the `view_stats` on this query?

Comment: When you say "pass parameter to view", do you mean "use function return value in WHERE clause"?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario yes :)

Comment: And `WHERE fullname = param1()` doesn't serve your needs because you want to hard-code the value at view creation time, rather than getting it evaluated every time you query the view?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario  no. I need the last query to pass a DYNAMIC paramater to the `view_stats` (the view i've created).

Answer (score 0):

An SQL view can be thought of as just a shorthand for including a canned subquery in other queries, so it can't do anything a normal query couldn't do. If the parameter needed to structurally change the query being run, you'd need the entire query to be inside a function of some sort.

It looks like all you're doing here is setting the WHERE clause, so you can just include in the view the column you want to filter on, and use a WHERE clause when querying it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution to improve the problem of slow VIEWS with multiple joins queries between multiple tables.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_QUERY_VIEW_WITH_PARAMETERS`(IN p_having VARCHAR(300))
    COMMENT 'Executes the statement'
BEGIN
  SET @v_having = p_having;
  SET @v_sql=CONCAT('SELECT 
                    id    AS id_emp  ,
                    user  AS emp_name,
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    FROM table1
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT 
                    idtifier_us    AS id_emp  ,
                    description    AS emp_name,
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    FROM table2');
SET @v_sql2 = CONCAT(@v_sql,@v_having);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @v_sql2;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;


CALL `SP_QUERY_VIEW_WITH_PARAMETERS`('having id_emp=63 and emp_name like ''VANDERLEI%'' and created_at between ''2019-05-01'' and ''2019-05-17''  ')
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation, it doesn't tell how it's supposed to solve the problem

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can pass parameters to your views in a simple manner by creating a Function to GET your values from Session Variables. See https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/14511760 for the technique. This is a copy of my create function you may wish to pattern after.
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION fn_getcase_id()
RETURNS MEDIUMINT(11)
DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN

## see stackoverflow.com/questions/14511760 and read ALL the info TWICE or MORE.  wh 04/13/2017

```
RETURN @sv_case_id;
```

END//

DELIMITER ;
You will need to create a similar FN (one for each variable).