# Does MySQL views load all data of all joined tables to memory

Tags: mysql

I have a case where I have three tables creating a many-to-many relation. The two main tables have FK referencing other tables as well.

I want to know what would lead to a better performance, creating a View with a lot of JOINS (about 7-8 tables some of them are big) and querying it once to get all the data, or executing 4 - 5 queries on the different tables to collect all the information required.

The fact is from the different 7-8 tables that I will join in the view to get all the data, I will need only 1 or 2 fields from each table only.

Does MySQL load all columns of all JOINed tables in the view into memory or only the columns in the SELECT and WHERE? or how does it behave and how does that affect the performance?

Comment: Please consider posting a sample of one of your views.  Could you also post TEXT results of EXPLAIN (your view).  Here is a URL for an idea of passing parameters that could be considered.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443677/passing-parameter-to-mysql-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Some `TEXTs` and `BLOBs` are stored "off-record".  So, if you don't need a column, do not ask for it -- else it will incur (perhaps) an extra disk hit.  Phrased another way, it is potentially bad for performance to say `SELECT *` instead if specifying just the columns you need.
- MySQL `VIEWs` are syntactic sugar.  They rarely (maybe ever) help performance.  In some situations, they are slower than the equivalent `SELECT`.
- Good `INDEXes` are the main key to performance.  Having the columns of the `WHERE` and `ON` clauses in indexes is a simplistic first step.  More: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql
- The best indexing for a many:many relationship:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table
- Each query incurs some overhead.  So, it is *usually* better to use as few queries as possible to perform a task.  For example, using one query to fetch a set of "ids", then building another query to act on the corresponding rows, is very likely to be slower than a combined query.
- If you need 7-8 tables to gather the info, consider whether the data is "over-normalized".

Consider providing a single `SELECT` plus the relevant `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`.  We can talk through that with less 'hand-waving'.