# passing parameter from PHP page into MySQL view

Tags: php, mysql

i am struggling to Pass Parameter('User_ID') from PHP page to View (SELLER_INFORMTION ) at MySQL DB. can you please guide me.

Code Below:

```
<?php
session_start();
userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
include '../Database.class.php';
$dbe_obj = new Database_Executer();
$query =  "SELECT * FROM SELLER_INFORMATION('$userid')";
$data = $dbe_obj-> select_query_executer($query);
?>

CREATE VIEW SELLER_INFORMATION
AS SELECT `PRODUCT`.PRODUCT_NAME,`CATEGORY`.CATEGORY_NAME,`SELLER_PRODUCT`.QUANTITY,
`SELLER_PRODUCT`.UNIT_PRICE,`SELLER_PRODUCT`.CURRENCY 
FROM `PRODUCT`,`SELLER_PRODUCT`,`CATEGORY`,`USERS`
 WHERE SELLER_PRODUCT.Category_ID=CATEGORY.CATEGORY_ID 
    AND SELLER_PRODUCT.Product_ID = PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID 
    AND SELLER_PRODUCT.User_ID=`USERS`.USER_ID 
    AND SELLER_PRODUCT.User_ID = '$userid'
    GROUP BY
    `PRODUCT`.PRODUCT_NAME,`CATEGORY`.CATEGORY_NAME,`SELLER_PRODUCT`.QUANTITY,
    `SELLER_PRODUCT`.UNIT_PRICE,`SELLER_PRODUCT`.CURRENCY 
    ORDER BY `CATEGORY`.CATEGORY_NAME DESC
```

Comment: Try using the proper syntax for a SQL query. You need a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Add `$` symbol infront of userid - `$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];`

Comment: Your view doesn't have a `USERID` column, how should `$userid` be used to select something from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your view to:

```
CREATE VIEW SELLER_INFORMATION
AS SELECT DISTINCT
          `PRODUCT`.PRODUCT_NAME,
          `CATEGORY`.CATEGORY_NAME,
          `SELLER_PRODUCT`.QUANTITY,
          `SELLER_PRODUCT`.UNIT_PRICE,
          `SELLER_PRODUCT`.CURRENCY,
          SELLER_PRODUCT.User_ID
FROM `PRODUCT`
JOIN `SELLER_PRODUCT` ON SELLER_PRODUCT.Product_ID = PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID 
JOIN `CATEGORY` ON SELLER_PRODUCT.Category_ID=CATEGORY.CATEGORY_ID 
JOIN `USERS` ON SELLER_PRODUCT.User_ID=`USERS`.USER_ID 
ORDER BY `CATEGORY`.CATEGORY_NAME DESC
```

Then use the query:

```
SELECT * FROM SELLER_INFORMATION WHERE User_ID = '$userid'
```

You can't have a PHP variable inside a view definition. You need to return the column in the `SELECT` list of the view, so you can compare with it in a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option, you can pass parameters to your views in a simple manner by creating a Function to GET your values from Session Variables. See https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/14511760 for the technique. This is a copy of my create function you may wish to pattern after.
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION fn_getcase_id()
RETURNS MEDIUMINT(11)
DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN

## see stackoverflow.com/questions/14511760 and read ALL the info TWICE or MORE.  wh 04/13/2017

```
RETURN @sv_case_id;
```

END//

DELIMITER ;
You will need to create a similar FN (one for each variable).