# create a view of query which contain a variable or param

Tags: mysql

i tried to find a solution with no luck, i want to create a view  of query which contain user defined variable.

**what i have done**

```
        $mdb->query("SET @rank = 1, @seq = 1, @last = null") or die(mysqli_error($mdb)); 

        $mdb->query("CREATE view  midterm_view AS 
                      SELECT m.*, @rank := if(@last = average, @rank, @seq) AS rank, 
                       @seq := @seq +1, @last := average
                FROM 
                (SELECT *, AVG(score) as average 
                      from midterm_result 
                      group by student_id) m") or die(mysqli_error($mdb));
```

**i get this error**

```
       View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter
```

how can i do this ?

Comment: Have you had an opportunity to check out the solution dated 9/26/2017?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a view with variable parameters, use [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html) instead

Comment: Stored procedures are NOT the only solution.  See answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, you can pass parameters to your views in a simple manner by creating a Function to GET your values from Session Variables.
See https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/14511760 for the technique. This is a copy of my create function you may wish to pattern after.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION fn_getcase_id()    
RETURNS MEDIUMINT(11)
DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN
# see stackoverflow.com/questions/14511760 and read ALL the info TWICE or MORE.  wh 04/13/2017
    RETURN @sv_case_id;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

You will need to create a similar FN (one for each variable).